# Android On Missed Calls Changed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, phone-call

I am looking for a way to react to the amount of missed calls changing.
I've figured out how to get the current number of missed calls, but what I would like to do is send it to a server, so I would need some kind of broadcast listener or service I assume.

I really have no idea here, can you guys help me out?

Comment: you can inherit PhoneStateListener and  update miss calls count in OnCallStateChanged,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968798/getting-phone-state-in-xamarin

Comment: Are you trying to react to it while the app is in the background?

Comment: @Saamer Yes, that's the idea. My main problem is to react to users "seeing" their missed calls, i.e. opening their phone app and thus clearing the missed calls.

Comment: So you would have to take what Cherry Bu shared, and mix that with the CallLog API from Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#MISSED_TYPE . This could help you with that part https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542452/xamarin-c-sharp-android-call-logs

Comment: @Saamer Pretty much, but as far as I can tell this does not notify me if the user has seen the missed calls, or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to do this using Java/Kotlin through Native development? Could you share a link if so?

Comment: @Saamer No, sadly I've got no idea.

Comment: I would recommend asking this question under android, java, kotlin. And if they say its possible and they share some code, I can convert that to C# for you! :)

Comment: @Saamer Thank you, I hope I will come back with answers!

Comment: Yeah because if you cant do it in Android native through Java/Kotlin, you can definitely not do it with Xamarin. And also the other way around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202435/discussion-between-schwefelhexa-and-saamer).

Comment: @Schwefelhexa, now you have solved your issue now, please share your answer if you solved your issue, thanks.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT No, sadly no response in the Android thread. I'm still in the prototyping phase, so I am now considering switching to Flutter.

Comment: @Schwefelhexa,If you find one solution, please remember to share it here, thanks.